# A case of limiting equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

I have noticed in the solutions of the problems of Friction of a physics book I'm studying from that in cases of **limiting equilibrium**, the force of friction $f$ to be equal to the coefficient of static friction multiplied by the normal contact force (N).

I know that should be used in cases of limiting equilibrium, but the book, while explaining the limiting friction and static friction, happens to use $f_{\max}$ and $f_{s}$ as their symbols.

Therefore, my question is, in case of limiting equilibrium, which force of friction is playing the role? Is it the limiting friction or the static friction?

I feel like it's the limiting friction that's playing the role but still for the book's usage of $f$ instead of using $f_{\max}$ or $f_{s}$, is making me very confused.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

$f_{\max}$ Denotes The Maximum Friction Force while $f_s$ Denotes the Static Friction Force. Usually Used When there is a Critical Position. Even A Negligible Force will Disturb the Equilibrium

$\mu ->$ Friction Coefficient

$N \to$ Normal Force

$f_{\max} = \mu\cdot N$

$f_{max}$ is the Maximum possible Friction Force that the Surface can exert on the Object.

I Like to Think of it as a Bank. When There is a Force Upto $f_{\max}$ Acting on the Object, The Friction Nullifies it. When $F > f_{\max}$, The Object Slips on the Surface.

$\mu_s \to$ Static Friction Coefficient

$f_{s} = \mu_s \cdot N$

$f_{s}$ is the Force Exerted By Static Friction. Static friction is the Force Exerted by A Surface on the Object When the Object is Initially at Rest. $f_{s}$ is Usually Larger than $f_{k}$(Kinetic Friction) Due to Cold Welding.

$\mu_k \to$ Kinetic Friction Coefficient

$f_{k} = \mu_s \cdot N$

$f_{k}$ is the Force Exerted by Friction When the Object is Slipping on the Surface.

[image: Friction Force vs Force]

As it is Seen, $f_{s} > f_k$ and After $F > f_{s}$, The Constant Force $f_{k}$ is The Friction Force.

Comment: Thanks very much, Sir, for answering to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting equilibrium is a condition when the object is on the verge of movement, it will move even if very little force is applied. In limiting condition author might have use f instead of $f_{\mathrm{max}}$ to avoid confusion (just opposite happened in your case ), you might have gone through problems where a block is in limiting equilibrium on a wedge, in that case only one component of normal is perpendicular to surface of contact and one component of weight is opposite to that component reducing the friction, hence instead of saying that it's *maximum friction*, it's better to simply use *friction*. Don't worry about terminology it is immaterial once you develop intuition by solving variety of problems.

Comment: Thanks very much, Sir, for answering to my question.